# Unable to update a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, warnings

I am receiving this warning "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state." I have looked through stack overflow and haven't found an answer that works for my situation. Everything looks correct to my eye so I am not sure what is going on. Here is the relevant code and I can post more if it is needed. I am in a process of breaking down my logic into separate components. the logic worked when I had it the way it was before, but now it is acting weird. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

parent component:

```
  <DisplayPoemList thoughtsProp={this.state.thoughts}  onClick={this.handleDeleteClick}      name='Delete Thoughts' />
```

child component:

```
    import React from 'react' 
    import { DisplayPoem } from '../DisplayPoem'

      export const DisplayPoemList = (props) => {
          return (
            <div className="flex-item-main">
                <ol>
                    {props.thoughtsProp.map((thought, index)=> 
                        <DisplayPoem className='displayPoem' key={index} onClick={props.onClick(index)} name={props.name} value={thought} />
                    )}
                </ol>
            </div> 
          )
      }
```

here is the previous, working, parent code which displays `displayPoem`

```
    <div className="flex-item-main">
         <ol>
            {this.state.thoughts.map((thought, index)=> 
                <DisplayPoem className='displayPoem' key={index} onClick={() => { this.handleDeleteClick(index) }} name='Delete Thoughts' value={thought} />
            )}
          </ol>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `onClick` callback of the child component from `props.onClick(index)` to `()=>props.onClick(index)`.

Comment: that totally fixed it, thank you so much! May I ask what the difference is? Why does it need an extra unnamed function?

Comment: Good thing it fixed that!! But I'm sorry that I don't remember the reason now.. My guess is that `onClick` expects a function object, but `props.onClick(index)` executes the function and then returns void. Thus `props.onClick(index)` is now being executed every time the component renders, making the component to re-render at the same time, which leads to an infinite loop.